# GitHub pull request reviews line comments behaviour

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

Recently GitHub introduced some new features including [Pull Request Reviews](https://github.com/blog/2256-a-whole-new-github-universe-announcing-new-tools-forums-and-features).

In the past, line comments in Pull Requests would collapse like this after the line was changed in further commits:

[image: Commented on an outdated diff]

Since the launch of the new feature, line comments no longer collapse even after further commits that address the issues. So far I've only had one PR and I'm not sure if the reviewer added single comments or used the new "Start a review" feature.

How can I get the old behaviour back or does it improve in the new "Start a review" feature?

I've watched their [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/HW0RPaJqm4g) on this feature and I can't determine whether the behaviour right now is what I'm supposed to be experiencing.

Comment: I am wondering the exact same thing. I have no idea why the are not more people commenting on this because this behaviour is extremely frustrating. I hope someone can provide a solution.

Comment: We're seeing the same behavior as the OP. It would be good to get the official word from GitHub about the updated workflow. Not being able to see the diff between when a comment was posted and when a fix was pushed is extremely frustrating for a reviewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent a message to GitHub support and received the following response:

> Sorry for the trouble! We are aware that with reviews comments no longer become "outdated" after new code is pushed.
>
> This is definitely on our radar as something we need to address. I can't give a timeline for it, but we will be looking into it soon.

Comment: I received the exact same response too when I went to "Contact a human" on GitHub support, hopefully it will be fixed soon!

Comment: It looks like they have fixed the issue. We now see collapsed outdated diffs as before.

Answer (score 0):

Since two years ago, GitHub now (august 2018) proposes "[Collapse all diffs in a pull request at once](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-08-17-collapse-all-diffs-in-a-pull-request-at-once/)":

> When a pull request contains a lot of changed files, code reviewers can find it hard to isolate the changes that are relevant to them.
>   **Now you can collapse (or expand) the contents of all diffs in a pull request by holding down the alt key and clicking on the inverted caret icon in any file header**.
>
> You can then go one step further by using the “`Jump to file or symbol`” dropdown to jump to the file that you’re interested in and automatically expand it.

That is not exactly the old behavior, but that does still improve the code review process.